# Fetch argument invalid type

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to execute this cunck of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_uniform([], minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0)
y = tf.random_uniform([], minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0)
default = lambda: tf.constant(0.0)
out = tf.case([(x < y, lambda: x + y), (x > y, lambda: x - y)], default)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run([x, y, default, out])
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument <function <lambda> at 0x10de7bf50> has invalid type <type 'function'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a function into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I am not sure what should not be a function here.

Comment: I don't know tensorflow, but it looks to me like the list being passed into `sess.run` has the form `[tensor, tensor, lambda func, tensor]`.  Did you mean to call `default()` instead there?

Comment: Yout're right, but now I get `ValueError: Operation u'random_uniform_34' has been marked as not fetchable.`

Comment: no idea about that one

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I was wrong and instead It's working. Thanks!